# update player time mysql

Tags: python, mysql

I want to update the date of the player's last visit, I made a request like this, but it doesn't work.

```
    sql2 = "UPDATE users SET date = VALUES (%s%s,%s) WHERE user_id = %s"
    val2 = (day.day, day.month, day.year, user_id)
```

I will be glad if you help me, thanks

Comment: Use auto-utilised timestamp column in a table where user actions are saved into (for example, this may be sessions table). Then you may obtain the date of last user activity by simple query.

Comment: [`VALUES()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_values) function may be used in `UPDATE .. ODKU` only.

Comment: @RiggsFolly, this doesn't work You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '2020-12-29) WHERE user_id = 5268' at line 1

Comment: Yea, missed what @Akina is saying, your syntax is all wrong. Check the MySQL manual for the format of an UPDATE. It does not have a VALUES()`

Comment: I removed VALUES and it worked, thanks @RiggsFolly